# Get json data into ioni view

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I have this controller...

```
"use strict";

var app = angular.module('ng-laravel');
app.controller('StartCtrl',function($scope, $http,$rootScope,$ionicLoading,$cordovaDevice,$cordovaVibration,ionicToast,$ionicPlatform,$cordovaNetwork){
    $http.get('https://www.myurl.com/stringjson').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.progetti = data.items;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // log error
    });
});
```

that correctly fetch json data like this:

```
    [{"id":2,"titolo":"The Marriage","descrizione":"Sal, a thirteen year old girl, narrates a story told
 by her Grandfather, which begins in a hospital room after Sal\u2019s Grandmother becomes ill during
 a road trip.  The story of The Marriage Bed flashes back to small-town Kentucky, where Sal\u2019s grandparents
 first met.  Gramps feels love at first sight for Gram, and courts her for the better part of a month
 before she accepts a marriage proposal.  On the night of their wedding, Gramps and Gram find a special
 bed in their new home: the bed that had belonged to Gramps\u2019 parents, and the bed that they\u2019ve
 slept in all of their lives since.  The tale ends with Sal wondering about her own romantic future.
  ","inizio":"2016-12-17 00:00:00","fine":2016,"goal":10000,"banner":"1457196511-29619972.png","entry_by"
:1,"created_at":"2016-03-05 17:48:31","updated_at":"2016-03-06 11:33:02","funded":"0","pledged":1000
,"image":"","id_categoria":5,"staff_picked":null,"vetrina":null,"summary":"A young girl traveling with
 her Grandparents recounts a favorite family love story ","numero_finanziatori":2,"active":1,"tags":""
,"banner3":"","image2":"","image3":"","motivazione":"Vediamo se funziona","didascalia":"Prova prova"
,"rating":5,"prima":0,"id_azienda":0,"banner2":""}
```

here is my view, where i'm unable to display data...

```
    <div class="hero no-header flat">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="app-icon"></div>
            <h2 class="light">Welcome</h2>
            <p class="stable">Our projects</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-controller="StartCtrl" class="item-avatar">
                <h2>{{ items[0].nome}}</h2>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    <div class="padding">
        <button type="submit" class="button button-full button-assertive ink">{{ data.nome }}</button>
        <button ui-sref="login" class="button button-full button-clear button-light">back to login</button>

    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing wrong variable ..

```
<ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-controller="StartCtrl" class="item-avatar">
                <h2>{{ progetti[0].titolo}}</h2>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

try this..
only `$scope` and `this` variables are auto synchronized.

Comment: Excuse me, wrong variable:) it is not nome but titolo